Itegrating ChatLiteLLM with LangChain
I have recently started to delve into architectures of chatbots and I have come across Ollama, LiteLLM, Langchain and the like. My idea would be to abstract a concise LLM from its actual usage in my i.e. chatbot code as far as possible (and sensible, of course). Ollama seems to be a good choice and can be used with OpenSource models, but can't interface with self-hosted models on Azure. Hence it's not the best abstraction tool.
Then I came across LiteLLM which seems to know Ollama models as well as Azure-based Models (via its ChatOpenAI-class). So to me, the obvious choice would be to use Ollama for the open source models operation/deployment and hide all self-hosted models and all cloud-based models behind a LiteLLM abstraction layer.
Interfacing with LiteLLM should work with Langchain, however, I ran into an issue:

I can use "ChatOpenAI" to interface with cloud-based Azure-hosted Models on my LiteLLM-Docker-Container:

ChatOpenAI(model_name=llm_opt, temperature=0, base_url="http://my-litellm-ip:m-litellm-port/v1", streaming=True, api_key="none")


I can also use "ChatOllama" to interface with self-hosted Ollama-models:

ChatOllama(
            model="llama3.2",
            temperature=0, base_url="http://my-ollama-ip:my-ollama-port", streaming=True,
        )


However, to my understanding, since I use LiteLLM as an abstraction layer, I should be able to just use every model in LiteLLM. It provides a "ChatLiteLLM" in the community packages, but running

ChatLiteLLM(api_base="http://my-litellm-ip:my-litellm-port/v1", model="gpt-4o", model_name="gpt-4o")

just gives me an error:

ValidationError: 1 validation error for ChatLiteLLM client Field required [type=missing, input_value={'api_base': 'http://192.... 'model_name': 'gpt-4o'}, input_type=dict] For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/missing

This is a bit odd since using the model with ChatOpenAI works, but not with ChatLiteLLM (even though the model is provided via the LiteLLM proxy server).
Has anybody used ChatLiteLLM and solved this problem? If not, is there an alternative to abstract my LLMs away from my chatbot code?
